# How do I change Material-UI MenuItem background on hover change from AutoComplete props?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[AutoComplete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) uses [Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu) to render MenuItems as shown in the docs on those pages.

I need to change the backgroundColor of the hovered MenuItem. I am able to change color of all items by using "menuItemStyle" which expects a style object but I'm not sure what the syntax for hover style is in the Material-UI style objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying hover style on root should do it.

```
const MyMenuItem = withStyles({
  root: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'red !important',
      color: 'blue'
    }
  }
})(MenuItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are still working on [hoverColor](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4227) which is possible in List Item.
But for the time being you can use these Props

```
<MenuItem 
  primaryText="MenuItem"
  onMouseEnter={(e) => e.target.style.backgroundColor= 'red'}
  onMouseLeave={(e) => e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'}/>
```

This might fix your problem temporarily.